# I want to get a unique id that push() had made

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm leaning Firebase.

I pushed some data in db like below

> ```
>  -test
>
>     -LBpjFMIPq-kQWyBmqf7
>
>        -str : value-a
> ```

but dataSnapshot.getKey() always get repository's name the "test".

How can I get the unique id that push() had made?

unique id is LBpjFMIPq-kQWyBmqf7 in this case.

```
package com.example.happy.firebasetest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String key;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref1 = database.getReference("test");

        ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                System.out.println(key);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

so key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            key = datas.getKey();
            System.out.println(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

You need to loop inside the `push()` key then use the method `getKey()` to retrieve the source location which is the unique id.